# How to set background color for code chunks in Quarto when output is Beamer?

Tags: latex, pdflatex, quarto, beamer, xelatex

I have the following code for a `Quarto` document:

````
---
title: "Any stuff"
date: 10/12/23
date-format: long
format: 
  beamer:
    aspectratio: 169
jupyter: python3
pdf-engine: xelatex
highlight-style: atom-one
code-block-bg: true
code-block-border-left: "#31BAE9"
code-line-numbers: true
---

## First slide

- Some stuff
- more stuff

## Slide with code


```{python}
#| echo: true
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = x + 5
print("Hello, world")
```
````

No matter what I do, the code is printed against the white background of Beamer. It seems that Quarto is ignoring my command, although it throws no error:

[image]

Comment: x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/698298/36296